# rolling-up consecutive duplicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Is there a way to "roll up" duplicate records such as time-series data in MySQL? I'm currently doing this in the application code after retrieving full time-series but the transmission of mostly redundant rows seems a nuisance. Here is an example:

Original data:

```
 date | state
..30  | A
..29  | A
..28  | A
..27  | D
..26  | D
..25  | A
```

Resultset with "rolled up" consecutive duplicate records:

```
 date | state
..28  | A
..26  | D
..25  | A
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `date` will be unique?

Comment: yes, date is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes that there will only be one record for any given date. It also does not check to make sure that dates are consecutive, if that's important.

```
SELECT the_date, my_state as the_state
  FROM (SELECT the_date
              ,if(@laststate = the_state, '', the_state) as my_state
              ,@laststate := the_state
          FROM myTest
         ORDER BY the_date
       ) sq
 WHERE my_state <> ''
 ORDER BY the_date DESC
;
```

First, in the subquery, it sets the state to an empty string if it's the same as the state in the previous row. Then, we select only those records form the subquery where the state is not an empty string.

See in [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wae3wCBYeZUzSLkGGBPn3/0).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want the first occurrence of state. How about...

```
select state,min(date) from your_table
group by state
```

**Edit:** I missed that you consider duplicates to restart after another row shows up. We could likely solve the problem via [analytic functions](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/) but it would be helpful to have example data in a table. Please put a sample on up SQL Fiddle or similar site.

Comment: No, this would give only one row with 'A'. They want two in the specific example.